# Get Counts according to Last Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this data in a table:

```
+-------------+-------+----------------+
| id   | Added | Removed | Date        |
+-------------+-------+----------------+
|  1   |  yes  |  yes    | 06-19-2016 |
|  2   |  yes  |  yes    | 06-19-2016 |
|  3   |  yes  | false   | 06-19-2016 |
|  4   |  false|  yes    | 09-19-2016 |
|  5   |  yes  |  yes    | 09-19-2016 |
|  6   |  false|  false  | 10-19-2016 |
|  7   |  false|  yes    | 10-19-2016 |
|  8   |  yes  |  false  | 10-19-2016 |
|  9   |  false|  yes    | 11-19-2016 |
+-------------+-------+-----------------+
```

I know total added and removed record for date wise is like

```
  Date        TotalRecordAdded TotalRecordRemoved 
06-19-2016          3                 2
09-19-2016          1                 2
10-19-2016          1                 1
11-19-2016          0                 1
```

What is the SQL Server query for getting this result?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, and tell us where you're stuck - we'll be glad to help, but we're not just writing the whole code for you....

Comment: You can do this quite easily by using (sum case when Added = 'yes'...) in your select clause. Also, I'd store the values as 0/1 instead of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation using `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.date,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.added = 'yes' THEN 1 END) as TotalRecordAdded,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.removed = 'yes' THEN 1 END) as TotalRecordRemoved
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.date
```